# Bootstrap - How to have columns on both sides of a long hight column?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For a specific reason I need to defy the laws of HTML to achieve something. So I would like to ask if anyone has a better mind in HTML than me.

I need te have a page filled with bootstrap cols; an in between these cols I want te define longer height blocks.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=1, X=1</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=1, X=2</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=1, X=3</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=1, X=4</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=1, X=5</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=1, X=6</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=1, X=7</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=1, X=8</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=1, X=9</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=1, X=10</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=1, X=11</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=1, X=12</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=2, X=1</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=2, X=2</div>
    <div class="long-element col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4" data-module-height="3" style="height: 639px;"></div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=2, X=7</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=2, X=8</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=2, X=9</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=2, X=10</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=2, X=11</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=2, X=12</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=3, X=1</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=3, X=2</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=3, X=7</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=3, X=8</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=3, X=9</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=3, X=10</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=3, X=11</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=3, X=12</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=4, X=1</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=4, X=2</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=4, X=7</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=4, X=8</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=4, X=9</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=4, X=10</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=4, X=11</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=4, X=12</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=5, X=1</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=5, X=2</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=5, X=3</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=5, X=4</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=5, X=5</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=5, X=6</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=5, X=7</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=5, X=8</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=5, X=9</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=5, X=10</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=5, X=11</div>
    <div class="col col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-1 col-lg-1" style="height: 213px;">Y=5, X=12</div>
</div>
```

Makes: [image]

I need the Y-numbers in columns vertically aligned, and the X-numbers horizontally. As you can see, the "Y=3, X=1" (and all others) are getting pushed to the right of the long-element. (Yes, that is default HTML behavior).

Is there any styling I can add to long-element/smaller cols to achieve the thing I need?

**EDIT:** Adding a fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/roboroads/dfLosb97/1/

Comment: Can You use JS in this project?

Comment: Do You need to have all cols visible, or those long cols can cover those "unused" cols?

Comment: I think in a row you should or you can only use 12 cols according to the bootstrap

Comment: That's right, but he can use position absolute to cover those cols, but there is need to use JS in this

Comment: there are total 52 cols which is effecting the layout so either it should be 48 or it should be 60 to get the exact layout

Comment: @bumerang Yes, i can use JS, but isn't preferred at all. And yes, all cols need to be visible.

Comment: @Amitsingh If you use more total col-width of 12, elements will go further on the next row. There is a total of that amount of cols, but the larger col is also 4 cols in width.

Comment: than the `height` is creating the issue you can use `max-height` to get the output

Comment: @Amitsingh The contents of the long element is resized by javascript to fit exactly into that box. Max-height wouldn't apply. Or do you have an other idea of how this should work?